# How can I find the other icon name of highcharts,I know "circle","triangle" so far

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

How can I find the other icon name of highcharts,I know "circle","triangle" so far,and I can use the other custom picturn such as [image] [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols/dark-unica/),What abount other offical icon?How many icons does it provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) is amazing. [Here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker) is a list of built in markers.